# Export/Import Metadata in PingFederate

Tags: single-sign-on, pingfederate

I am using PingFederate to act both as IdP server and SP server. After which i have OpenToken adapters for each components. And i have created **IdP-to-SP Adapter Mapping** under **Server Configuration** setting using the newly created Adapters.

And moving forward to **SP CONNECTIONS > IdP Configuration** section , i have created a new connection.

After which in **Server Configuration > Administrative Functions > MetaData Export** , i have exported the newly created SP Connections.

Now when i tried to use the metadata in **SP Configuration > IDP Connections > Create New** , the export functionality works fine but the data that was supposed to be loaded from the .xml file is not happening.

Here is what my metadata.xml file looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="localhost:default:entityId" cacheDuration="PT1440M" ID="Kuvm5eRQl_BYQ27ZVtV4OCcHb.1">


-<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">


-<ds:SignedInfo>

<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>

<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>


-<ds:Reference URI="#Kuvm5eRQl_BYQ27ZVtV4OCcHb.1">


-<ds:Transforms>

<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>

<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>

</ds:Transforms>

<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>

<ds:DigestValue>wn/+y44KVd1I0RfdGVnq7NGW9wc=</ds:DigestValue>

</ds:Reference>

</ds:SignedInfo>

<ds:SignatureValue> pX78c96Eq//dZQIRIzEFquvcnzlnrOh4Nnfdfc5BNgdpokdnBEE91Cr20YatuQqHg61XssjVoyLi 4HfzhAqf85ni+p/NyEi8iQx86W3JptmawzkA1nFY8+JD6m/WIblipHh/1l63tF1N0akoNwhbDhky jmiBpPgPc8FxJAOPE7k= </ds:SignatureValue>


-<ds:KeyInfo>


-<ds:X509Data>

<ds:X509Certificate> MIICRzCCAbCgAwIBAgIGAUIOacSJMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMGYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYD VQQIEwJDTzEPMA0GA1UEBxMGRGVudmVyMQwwCgYDVQQKEwNEZXYxDTALBgNVBAsTBFBpbmcxHDAa BgNVBAMTE0NvbmZpZyBTaWduaW5nIENlcnQwIBcNMTMxMDMxMTIwODAxWhgPMjExMzEwMDcxMjA4 MDFaMGYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIEwJDTzEPMA0GA1UEBxMGRGVudmVyMQwwCgYDVQQK EwNEZXYxDTALBgNVBAsTBFBpbmcxHDAaBgNVBAMTE0NvbmZpZyBTaWduaW5nIENlcnQwgZ8wDQYJ KoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBALD4NA4uYzAxWBih6BXwyPSFlw94dolpigT1FrTeT/SGAlAg teWp2Fy2LB0mVm2tSmRyYOi85c8M9jRjaB8SB688C1Q6TqNUvhfhje46GqDuUPxguCXHZsNS9XwM trWwGzm7IenVL1WJ4LHPJI0OYt8qH7nZ6FFUDW0fbuIMMLo/AgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAD gYEAkzykqYJasH8Tms2QlFa5HNWL1q8dpbp6ksEOi4E1mL1SZGs7iWM8ltYfMro1mGF/SWWxfStJ EEWiA01AigehJn2w5VPysYZxODBO1jYzRSyZo8hU8ioMcSZTpwgokzUZmMlwDhrbzDQmdh//sbri 1QB59uqG0CwU2/AJV3KU2KM= </ds:X509Certificate>

</ds:X509Data>


-<ds:KeyValue>


-<ds:RSAKeyValue>

<ds:Modulus> sPg0Di5jMDFYGKHoFfDI9IWXD3h2iWmKBPUWtN5P9IYCUCC15anYXLYsHSZWba1KZHJg6Lzlzwz2 NGNoHxIHrzwLVDpOo1S+F+GN7joaoO5Q/GC4Jcdmw1L1fAy2tbAbObsh6dUvVYngsc8kjQ5i3yof udnoUVQNbR9u4gwwuj8= </ds:Modulus>

<ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>

</ds:RSAKeyValue>

</ds:KeyValue>

</ds:KeyInfo>

</ds:Signature>


-<md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">


-<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">


-<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">


-<ds:X509Data>

<ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>

</ds:X509Data>

</ds:KeyInfo>

</md:KeyDescriptor>

<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>

<md:SingleSignOnService Location="https://localhost:9031/idp/SSO.saml2" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>

</md:IDPSSODescriptor>

<md:ContactPerson contactType="administrative"/>

</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

And the `entityId` attribute in `.xml` file points to `localhost:default:entityId` but ain't it suppose to be the **Partner's Entity Id of SP Connection**. It looks like it is extracting value from **Server Setting > Federal Info** of global server setting. 
Question :

1. So is the `entityId` supposed to be extracted from Federal Info or SP
   Connection ?
2. How to map SP Connection and IdP connection ?
3. What are the field that are populated by the `metadata.xml` file ?

Reference :

[Training Video](https://www.pingidentity.com/support/training-center/index.cfm/103-creating-a-connection?id=1011570451001)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, your entityId is set globally under Server Setting > Federation Info. So that is what you will see when you export generic or connection level meta-data to share with Partners. The value you enter into the actual IDP or SP Connection is your PARTNER'S entityId. In this case, since you are acting as the IDP and SP at the same time, the entityId values will be the same (localhost:default:entityId) in your IDP and SP Connection which can be confusing.

If needed, you can override the server-level default entityId by utilizing the Virtual Server ID which will override the **Issuer** value for a given connection.

You can find more information on these fields in the [PingFedate Admin Guide](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF71/General+Information)

--Ian